# Clone a program which uses a logical database, programmatically

Tags: abap

I have a report, let's call it `REPORT_A`, and I'd like to clone it to `REPORT_B`, execute `REPORT_B`, and then come back.

I'm doing the following:

```
  DATA: lv_report_name     TYPE c LENGTH 30 VALUE `DEMO_LIST_OUTPUT`,
        lv_new_report_name TYPE c LENGTH 30 VALUE `ZZ_DEMO_LIST_OUTPUT`,
        lt_report_code     TYPE abaptxt255_tab,
        lv_message         TYPE abaptxt255,
        lv_line            TYPE i,
        lv_word            TYPE abaptxt255.

  READ REPORT lv_report_name INTO lt_report_code.

  SYNTAX-CHECK FOR lt_report_code
    MESSAGE  lv_message
    LINE     lv_line
    WORD     lv_word.

  IF sy-subrc = 0.

    INSERT REPORT lv_new_report_name FROM lt_report_code STATE 'A'.

    GENERATE REPORT lv_new_report_name.

    SUBMIT  (lv_new_report_name) VIA SELECTION-SCREEN AND RETURN.

  ENDIF.
```

The `syntax-check` statement is returning `sy-subrc = 4`, and `lv_message` contains:

> PERNR is not defined for the current logical database

This is the issue -> `REPORT_A` uses `PNP` logical database and has a `get pernr`statement, so it fails the syntax-check.

Detail: `REPORT_A` is working just fine, `tables pernr` is declared in it. If I run it alone in `SE38`, it executes perfectly.

But, due to this weird error, I am always failing to generate `REPORT_B`.

Even if I skip the `IF` condition, it will then DUMP in the `submit` line, pointing a syntax error referring to the same error, `"pernr is not defined for the current logical database"`.

Is there a way around it?

Can I call `get pernr` dynamically, so it doesn't fail the syntax check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, be careful, [`INSERT REPORT`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapinsert_report.htm) and [`GENERATE REPORT`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapgenerate_report.htm) are statements **for internal use** (reserved to SAP).

If you still want to use the internal statements, see the rest of my answer.

Otherwise the workaround is to use [`GENERATE SUBROUTINE POOL`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapgenerate_subroutine_pool.htm). But it won't work for a logical database. If you copy a standard program maybe it's not a good idea of copying it (**no note assistant to help you in case of patch/upgrade**), so the classic workarounds are to add [implicit enhancement options](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenimplicit_enh_points.htm), or use eventual user exits proposed by SAP in this particular program (if any). There might be other options, but it depends on your exact goal, which you didn't share (yet).

---

The statement `INSERT REPORT` creates a source code module with a program entry (in table `TRDIR`) which by default corresponds to an [Executable program](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenexecutable_program_glosry.htm) (A.K.A. "report"), and so can be executed with `SUBMIT`.

But in your case, the program you want to generate is a [program using a Logical Database](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenldb_usage_executable.htm), so you must assign the program attribute `Logical database` (`TRDIR-LDBNAME`).

The program attributes are to be passed via the words **`DIRECTORY ENTRY`** in the following statements:

- [`SYNTAX-CHECK ... DIRECTORY ENTRY ls_trdir`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapsyntax-check_for_itab.htm)
- `INSERT REPORT ... DIRECTORY ENTRY ls_trdir`

An easy solution for copying an existing program is to read its program attributes from the table `TRDIR`, change the name of the program (`TRDIR-NAME`) that you are creating, and pass them after the words `DIRECTORY ENTRY`.

Additional comments:

- `COMMIT WORK` should be placed after `GENERATE REPORT` as explained in the documentation.
- `SY-SUBRC` should be checked after `INSERT REPORT` and `GENERATE REPORT`.

Consequently, the following code will work:

```
  DATA: lv_report_name     TYPE c LENGTH 30 VALUE `DEMO_LIST_OUTPUT`,
        lv_new_report_name TYPE c LENGTH 30 VALUE `ZZ_DEMO_LIST_OUTPUT`,
        lt_report_code     TYPE abaptxt255_tab,
        lv_message         TYPE abaptxt255,
        lv_line            TYPE i,
        lv_word            TYPE abaptxt255,
        ls_trdir           TYPE trdir.

  READ REPORT lv_report_name INTO lt_report_code.
  SELECT SINGLE * FROM trdir INTO ls_trdir WHERE name = lv_report_name.
  ls_trdir-name = lv_new_report_name.

  SYNTAX-CHECK FOR lt_report_code
    MESSAGE  lv_message
    LINE     lv_line
    WORD     lv_word
    DIRECTORY ENTRY ls_trdir.

  IF sy-subrc = 0.

    INSERT REPORT lv_new_report_name FROM lt_report_code STATE 'A' DIRECTORY ENTRY ls_trdir.
    IF sy-subrc = 0.

      GENERATE REPORT lv_new_report_name.
      IF sy-subrc = 0.

        COMMIT WORK.

        SUBMIT  (lv_new_report_name) VIA SELECTION-SCREEN AND RETURN.

      ELSE.
* Handle the error + rollback
      ENDIF.
    ELSE.
* Handle the error + rollback
    ENDIF.
  ELSE.
* Handle the error
  ENDIF.
```

Comment: hello, Sandra, thank you for the precise answer, it was exactly as you said. I did the modifications proposed and it worked just fine!